# If I connect an interface which is not set up in operation system to a switch, should the link LED light up?

Tags: networking, hardware, switch

Patch-cords are checked with a tester and they are OK.
LEDs are not burning neither on switch ports, nor on the blades' interfaces. Interfaces on blades are NOT set up, so the question is: should they burn in this case?
Or does it depends on hardware?

Comment: It depends, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the hardware. I've seen hardware configure in two ways.

- LED lights up when connected to a powered cable (attached to a switch).  This provides a quick indication that the cable is connected end to end.
- LED lights up when the driver software sets up a connection.  This provides a clear indication that the interface has been configured (although possibly incorrectly).  The color of the light may change depending on the speed at which the interface is configured.

In either case the LED usually flashes when traffic is flowing.

Comment: As far as I know, on some Juniper switches LED flashing frequency indicates the speed of a port (100 or 1000 megabits per second, for instance).